# php how to curl if CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS is in a loop

Tags: php, curl

I am a new php developer , has a project now need to call a third part API. so I use CURL function , they return xml file and everything working fine as expected

Question I need to call the API as **POST** method , and I need to pass values. so I wrote down all the parameter like this

```
$parameter = array(
        'op_id'        => 'asdasdasdasdads',
        'secret_key'   => 'hahah',
        'product_code' => '1234556',
        'site_code'    => '598',
        'start_date'    => "$start_date",
        'end_date'    => "$end_date"
);
```

I need to call this API every 30 mins , so I can put the php file on CRON job. but the problem is I need to pass the start_date and end_date as variables. so like this

```
start:2011-12-22 07:00:00 end:2011-12-22 07:30:00
start:2011-12-22 07:30:00 end:2011-12-22 08:00:00 
start:2011-12-22 08:00:00 end:2011-12-22 08:30:00 
start:2011-12-22 08:30:00 end:2011-12-22 09:00:00
```

i want to make it dynamic , impossible i come to the file change the start and end date every 30 mins.
so I loop through it

```
$interval = 1800; // Interval in seconds
$date_first     = "2011-12-22 07:00:00";
$date_second    = "2011-12-22 10:30:00";
$time_first     = strtotime($date_first);
$time_second    = strtotime($date_second);
for ($i = $time_first; $i < $time_second; $i = $i + $interval){
    $start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $i);
    $end_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $i + $interval );
    $parameter = array(
    'op_id'        => 'asdasdasdasdads',
    'secret_key'   => 'hahah',
    'product_code' => '1234556',
    'site_code'    => '598',
    'start_date'    => "$start_date",
    'end_date'    => "$end_date"  
    );
}
```

if I put all the CURL inside the for loop it works , but my server IP may be block by third party. because it will call multiple times as long as the loop is working.

I put sleep(), inside the loop seems not working , any idea ? 
or I can put curl outside the loop , but are there any solutions/funcitons I can use make CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS changes every 30 mins according to my loop ?

Appreciated in advance , Had been thinking for 3 days

here are my curl execution.

```
$parameter = array(
    'op_id'        => 'asdasdasdasdads',
    'secret_key'   => 'hahah',
    'product_code' => '1234556',
    'site_code'    => '598',
    'start_date'   => '2011-12-22 07:00:00',
    'end_date'     => '2011-12-22 07:30:00' 
);

$url = "http://www.api.thirdparty.net";
$curl = curl_init();        
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);   
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);   
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameter);   

$output = curl_exec($curl);

if( $output === FALSE ){
    echo "cURL ERRORS " . curl_error($curl);
}

curl_close($curl);    
$xml = simplexml_load_string($output);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to change your code to much.  If you set your cron job up to run every 30 minutes then the code I have will use the date() and strtotime() functions to set your start and end dates for you based off when the cron job runs.

Like so:

```
$parameter = array(
    'op_id'        => 'asdasdasdasdads',
    'secret_key'   => 'hahah',
    'product_code' => '1234556',
    'site_code'    => '598',
    'start_date'   => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'end_date'     => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '+ 30 minutes'))
);


$url = "http://www.api.thirdparty.net";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameter);

$output = curl_exec($curl);

if( $output === FALSE ){
    echo "cURL ERRORS " . curl_error($curl);
}

curl_close($curl);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($output);
```

The only problem you may encounter is that the date used will be the date of the timezone of your server.  That timezone may not be the same timezone as the api.  If that is the case then you can change the timezone to the timezone that you need in order to get the right datetime.

Just add this at the top of your code if you need to:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); //<---Pick your timezone.
```

Comment: Thanks , How stupid am I ! that would work perfectly.